# Union type specialization within a function in Julia

Tags: types, julia

Say I have a function where the `c` keyword argument is a `Union` type. Depending on the type for `c` I would like to do some stuff within the function:

```
function foo(a :: Integer, b :: AbstractFloat; c :: Union{Integer, AbstractFloat} = nothing)
    if typeof(c) <: AbstractFloat
        d = c / pi
    elseif typeof(c) <: Integer
        d = typeof(b)(c ^ 2)
    end
    return d
end
```

Is this the correct way for dealing with this scenario? Should I instead use the multiple dispatch for a more efficient implementation? I am also thinking in terms of performance here.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, attention you can't dispatch based on keyword arguments, only positional ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments.

This part:

```
c::Union{Integer, AbstractFloat} = nothing
```

will not compile, you would have to write `c::Union{Nothing, Integer, AbstractFloat} = nothing`.

In general the `typeof(c) <: AbstractFloat` should be optimized out by the compiler since the compiler knows the exact type of `c` you are passing, so this style should not impact the performance of your code.

However, there are two considerations:

1. Using multiple methods would probably lead to a cleaner code.
2. If you use `Union` you have to be more careful when defining methods to avoid dispatch ambiguities. Here is an example:

```
julia> f(x::Int, y::Union{Int, Float64}) = "f1"
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x::Integer, y::Int) = "f2"
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(1, 1)
ERROR: MethodError: f(::Int64, ::Int64) is ambiguous.
```

which is sometimes considered as surprising (although it is a correct behavior technically)

EDIT. Here is an example when the compiler does not complain as it can always establish a more specific method:

```
julia> g(x::Int, y::Union{Int, Float64}) = "f1"
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(x::Integer, y::Union{Int, Float64}) = "f2"
g (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> g(1, 1)
"f1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why would that be "surprising" though? For me makes sense that the compiler complains about two same-name methods potentially accepting the same types?

Comment: Also, the `c :: Union{Integer, AbstractFloat} = nothing` part actually compiles?

Comment: If you try to evaluate your `foo` function without passing `c` argument you get an error. As for "surprising" I will give you an example when compiler does not complain. I will edit the answer.